# Using Azure ACS to get access to underlying identity provider's access/refresh token

Tags: azure, oauth, acs

I couldn't find any clear indication of whether ACS provided this functionality or not.

I would like to leverage ACS to do most of my authentication work, but I would also like access to the identity provider's access/refresh token that was sent to ACS. I can then make API calls to the identity provider to access the user's data such as calendar or profile information (assuming I've requested this access during the application authorization steps).

Is this possible using ACS? It seems as if ACS abstracts most of the underlying identity provider information out, and only provides an ACS token used purely for authentication purposes, not for use in talking directly to the identity provider.

Comment: Just FYI, [ACS is being deprecated](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/02/12/the-future-of-azure-acs-is-azure-active-directory.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @BenV ! I wasn't aware of that. Probably best not to start building on top of a deprecated product.

Comment: it is **not** being depricated! Even if you build something today, you will be able to move it later when these features are migrated to Azure AD. The fact that ACS got **just** updated for the Google OpenID Connect speaks for itself!

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @astaykov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no :)

ACS does support this feature for the providers that do support that. It is not explicitly documented, because it is not special. ACS does **not** "just  create own token for pure authentication purposes".

If you take the FaceBook IdP, ACS does provide you the FaceBook token, which you can use to query the FaceBook Graph API. And what permissions for the API you will get, depends on what permissions your FaceBook Application will require from authenticating user. I am not sure about the level of sophistication of FaceBook consent framework, but the last I plaid with it, the authenticating user could only Accept all required consents, or reject all. He was not able to selectively chose which consents to grant to your application, out of all requested.

Having said that, from Google Authentication Provider, you do not receive additional tokens. At least with the old OpenID 2.0 imeplementation. Now with the deprication of OpenID 2.0 and moving Google to OpenID Connect, there is a requirement that you explicitly register your ACS Namespace as application with Google. At that point, I assume (speculation of mine) you may declare requested consents, just as you do with FaceBook. And if Google sends the token, you will definitely receive it in your application through the ACS.

ACS is super powerful service that will not die. As in the referenced blog post, all of its features will sooner or later be moved to Azure AD itself. And a migration plan will be provided (hopefully :) ).

But also, note that ACS do only talk with Yahoo, Google, Facebook, Azure AD and any WS-Federation IdP. And WS-Federation protocol is not known for being very flexible and giving you the flexibility you want. ACS in theory also [supports OAuth 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh801906.aspx), but its support does not include Federation, only local identity management (identities local to ACS self).

Also, note, that ACS is being used by a lot of Microsoft owned services, like Visual Studio Online, [Azure Service Bus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn170478.aspx) and others. ACS is neither dead, nor will just die letting all its customers on the wild.

You can decide to use it today. Or you can decide to use whatever features are today available in the Azure AD itself. Or wait until ACS is fully migrated to Azure AD.